# Mysql Select statement find records not in the table

Tags: mysql

I have a table A in which I have the following 5 records

```
ID
---
1
2
3
4
5
```

I need a query that will return records not found in the table, something along the lines of:

```
select ID from A where ID in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I would like to see ID 6 returned since and ID of 6 is not found in the table.

```
ID
---
6
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to store the values you want to find in a table (probably a temporary table), and then left join these tables:

```
create temporary table temp_values (
    val int not null,
    index idx_val(val)
);
insert into temp_values (val) values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);

select 
    t.val
from 
    temp_values as t
    left join yourTable as a on t.val = a.id
where 
    a.id is null;
```

Hope this helps.